# How to set ServiceUser?

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a Azure mobile service .NET backend. When debugging locally I want to set the ServiceUser in code.

I've tried to add a DelegatingHandler like this:

```
    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.ServiceUser user = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.ServiceUser(new GenericIdentity("myuser"));
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
        HttpContext.Current.User = user;
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Everything seems to work, but then in my TableController my code does not give me back the same user.

```
        var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
```

Can this be done? How can I set the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more details as to why you need to set the ServiceUser? Is it for some kind of a test? If you provide more information someone might provide you with more elegant solution.